# New Raspberry Pi Pico disconnects during MicroPython installation

Tags: usb, setup, pi-pico, micropython

I have a problem setting up a new RaspPi Pico. I pressed the BOOTSEL button, connected it via USB to my Windows machine and released the button. I copied the .uf2 file previously downloaded for this version of the Pico (regular Pico, without WLAN) from [raspberrypi.com](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/micropython.html#drag-and-drop-micropython).
It rebooted and I re-connected it. I installed Thonny and wanted to select MicroPython on the bottom right, but it was not available. The Pico had disconnected. Again, I pressed the BOOTSEL button and connected the Pico. Now, Thonny gave me the option to install MicroPython.
I tried this 3 or 4 times, always with the same events happening:

1. Press BOOSEL, connect via USB, release BOOTSEL
2. Select install MicroPython v. 1.19.1 in Thonny
3. Copying files 1...100 %
4. Port not found! Thonny says "Done!" anyway, but MicroPython cannot be selected.
5. Pico was unmounted for some reason

Here is the Thonny output during installation attempts:

```
Downloading from https://micropython.org/resources/firmware/rp2-pico-20220618-v1.19.1.uf2
Writing to H:\rp2-pico-20220618-v1.19.1.uf2
100%
Waiting for the port...
Warning: Could not find port in 10 seconds

Done!
```

What have I done wrong or where is the problem? Has someone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Ah this is a common problem, not confined to Pico installation. Usually Windows tries to be clever and finds a new port when asked to install the same package again. A troubleshooting trick to use the control panel to check out what ports are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tlfong01 pointed out, this appears to be a Windows related issue. I "solved" it in the simplest possible way: by using a notebook running Linux to connect with the Pico.